# best strategy for probabilities problem

Tags: probability-theory, optimization

Background:I came up with this problem when my son approached me about trying to go as late as possible to give his oral presentation

You and eight other classmates failed an exam, luckily your teacher Mrs. Robinson is giving you an opportunity to make up the exact for a presentation. There's three days to present and three students will present per day, the teacher either chooses randomly from a bag or a volunteer will present. You have nothing done, but you can learn from each student to wing your presentation.               Fortunately three of your friends also failed the exam and are willing to volunteer so you have time to work on your presentation. When would be the best day for your friends to volunteer? The later you go the better your grade will be in preparation.
Id like to know:Whats the best strategy and can this strategy be generalized for different values of F and S (friends and students respectively)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the first presentation be at time $1$, the second at time $2$, etc. We want to maximize the time that our hero is expected to do his/her presentation, i.e.,
$$\frac{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5+n_6}{6},$$
where $n_i\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ (with all $n_i$s being different from each other) are the times possible after our hero's three mates have chosen their spots. But clearly for this expression to be as big as possible, we should choose the $n_i$s to be as large as possible, so the three friends should volunteer to do the first three presentations.

This holds no matter how many students and friends there are (the friends should always go first).